# Connection forms on manifolds in Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry

This question comes from trying to generalize something that it easy to see for surfaces.

Start with an oriented surface smoothly embedded in Euclidean space. The embedding determines two mappings of the unit tangent circle bundle into Euclidean space.

Given a unit length tangent vector,e, at p the first map sends it to the parallel vector at the origin. The second map maps e to its 90 degree positively oriented tangential rotation.

These two maps, e and ie, determine a 1 form on the tangent circle bundle. It is the euclidean inner product of de, the differential of e, with the vector ie.

It is standard and easy to see that w determines a Levi Civita connection on the surface. That is: w is invariant under rotations of the tangent circles and is normalized.

I tried to generalize this construction to higher dimensional manifolds. In this case one gets n-1 one forms like e but I had trouble showing invariance under rotation.

What is the correct generalization?

Comment: You may want to take a look in the Foundations of Differential Geometry Vol 1, by Kobayashi,Nomizu